# Напечатать слова предложения в таком порядке, чтобы последняя буква каждого слова совпадала с первой буквой следующего слова

Tags: java

Дана задача : В предложении все слова начинаются с различных букв. Напечатать  слова предложения в таком порядке, чтобы последняя буква каждого слова совпадала с первой буквой следующего слова.

На данный момент существует такой код, который работает некорректно, так как не выводит слова в нужном порядке:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] StrArray = new String[]{"Яблоки", "Олег", "Башня", "Гриб"};
           for(int i = 0; i < StrArray.length - 1; i++) {
              for(int j = i+1; j < StrArray.length; j++){
                if(StrArray[i].charAt(StrArray[i].length()-1) == StrArray[j].charAt(0)){
                String tmp = StrArray[j];
                StrArray[j] = StrArray[i+1];
                StrArray[i+1] = tmp;
            }
            if (StrArray[i].charAt(0) == StrArray[j].charAt(StrArray[j].length()-1)){
                String tmp = StrArray[i];
                StrArray[j] = StrArray[i+1];
                StrArray[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i =0;i<=StrArray.length-1;i++){
        System.out.println(StrArray[i]);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: что не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что условие гарантирует наличие такой цепочки, видимо - единственной, поэтому решение достаточно простое, вопрос только в организации данных. Размер набора данных  позволяет ограничиться несложным квадратичным алгоритмом (хотя можно быстрее).

Подобная попытка и была сделана, но что происходит в массиве при обменах?
Кроме того, в примере сравниваются строчные и прописные буквы. Если уж есть такая нужда, то их следует привести к одному регистру.

Ситуацию [можно исправить](https://ideone.com/ZzVK0M) сдвигом части массива вправо в цикле (подобно тому, как делается в сортировке вставками)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] StrArray = new String[]{"яблоки", "олег", "башня", "гриб"};
           for(int i = 0; i < StrArray.length - 1; i++) {
              for(int j = i+1; j < StrArray.length; j++){
                if(StrArray[i].charAt(StrArray[i].length()-1) ==StrArray[j].charAt(0)){
                String tmp = StrArray[j];
                for(int k = j; k > i + 1; k--)
                     StrArray[k] = StrArray[k-1];
                StrArray[i+1] = tmp;
            }
            if (StrArray[i].charAt(0) == StrArray[j].charAt(StrArray[j].length()-1)){
                String tmp = StrArray[j];
                for(int k = j; k > i; k--)
                     StrArray[k] = StrArray[k-1];
                StrArray[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i =0;i<=StrArray.length-1;i++){
        System.out.println(StrArray[i]);
    }
 }
}

гриб
башня
яблоки
олег
```

Альтернатива - взять ArrayList, который позволяет добавлять элементы в начало и конец.

```
Вставили в него первое слово массива.  
Теперь в каждый момент у нас есть последний символ цепочки last и первый first. 
Пока ещё есть неиспользованные слова:
    Перебираем оставшиеся слова. 
    Если первый символ совпадает с last, вставляем слово в конец списка, обновляем last.
    Если последний символ совпадает с first, вставляем слово в начало списка, обновляем first.
```